# How to give role to user for reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

If user add reaction `:HotS_Tank:` in a special message, the bot will need to give this role to user, but I do not have any idea how to do it...

That's what I have tried:

```
async def role_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    roleChannel = discord.Object(id='411270826374070293')
    roleMSG1 = client.get_message(roleChannel, id='411657109860515840')
    roleMSG2 = client.get_message(roleChannel, id='411657144488689674')
        while not client.is_closed:
            reac1 = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji=':HotS_Tank:411445724287598592',message=roleMSG1)
    if reac1.reaction.emoji == ':HotS_Tank:411445724287598592':
        await client.add_roles(reac1.user, roleHOTS_Tank)
client.loop.create_task(role_background_task())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation, there's an event called `on_reaction_add` [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add). You can simply use that.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    roleChannelId = '411270826374070293'

    if reaction.message.channel.id != roleChannelId:
        return #So it only happens in the specified channel
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:HotS_Tank:411445724287598592>":
        await client.add_roles(user, roleHOTS_Tank)
```